# Adding dependency assembly custom workflow activity in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to develop custom workflow activity for Dynamics CRM 2011, but I require to use third-party library in my operations, let's say `Newtonsoft.Json`.

But when I try to upload assembly combined with ILMerge I get following:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///d:\Workspace\Application4\Application4\bin\Debug\result.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.AssemblyReader.LoadAssembly(String path)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.AssemblyReader.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String path)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.AssemblyReader.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String path)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.RegistrationHelper.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String pathToAssembly)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.PluginRegistrationForm.btnLoadAssembly_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I'm trying to embed library directly into assembly by method described [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Embed%20DotNetZip), I get the same error.

Is there any workaround to deliver .NET dependency up to CRM? Or the only way is to put it into the GAC on the server?

Comment: Depends which library you are merging. Some libraries don't create problems when combined using ILMerge, some yes. If you are OnPremise you can put inside the GAC, is the supported way to do. You can always decompile the library and include the decompiled source in your custom activity (but depends the library if this approach is permitted or not)

Comment: @GuidoPreite, actually I have found one more way — embedding library and using reflection to call it's methods... It's not that fast, but if you don't have access to the server GAC it will work.

Comment: There are a few problems that can cause this, but the most common problem I have found is mixing 32 bit and 64 bit dlls. Make sure all DLLs and tools, including the Plugin Registration tool, are all built as either 32 or 64 bit and see if it that solves it for you.